# parse an array as a Json string using DataContractJsonSerializer WP7

Tags: arrays, parsing, windows-phone-7, datacontractjsonserializer

How can I parse the elements of an array in a Json string using DataContractJsonSerializer?
The syntax is:

```
{
   "array":[
 {
  "elementsProperies":"SomeLiteral"
 }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't necessarily "parse" a json string using DataContractJsonSerializer, but you can deserialize it into an object or list of objects using this. Here is a simple way to deserialize it to a list of objects if this is what you're after.

First you need to have an object type you plan on deserializing to:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyElement
{
    [DataMember(Name="elementsProperties")] // this must match the json property name
    public string ElementsProperties { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use something like the following method to deserialize your json string to a list of objects

```
private List<MyElement> ReadToObject(string json)
{
    var deserializedElements = new List<MyElement>();
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedElements.GetType());
        deserializedElements = ser.ReadObject(ms) as List<MyElement>;
    }
    return deserializedUsers;
}
```

Comment: you can also look into other json deserializers like json.net

Comment: thanks a bunch =D 
I already found the "solution" though. ( and idd, I used the deserialize method =3 ) What I did, with my retard head, is giving both the List in which to store the data, and also the element that I wanted to store the [DataContract] prefix.  ( I started with just the element but only later decided to use a List to store data, and forgot about the [DataContract]. 
I'm sorry, but forgot to delete the question. ( should I, or should I keep it for future reference? )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

In it you would just call:

```
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(yourjsonstring);

var elPropertyValue = (string)jsonObj.SelectToken("array[0].elementsProperies");
```

to get the `"SomeLiteral"`.