# How to parse a json object array containing mixed primitive types using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datacontractjsonserializer

How can I parse the JSON object below using `DataContractJsonSerializer` in C#?

I will need to define a class to hold the below JSON data, which includes an array of arrays of primitives of mixed types (string and integer):

```
Body:
    {
      "status": "failure",
      "staticdata": [
        [
          "2013-06-01",
          123
        ],
        [
          "2013-06-02",
          234
        ],
        [
          "2013-06-03",
          345
        ],    
        ...
      ]
    }
```

I tried the below answer and tried to read through `DataContractJsonSerializer`,

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response);

RootObject jsonResponse = objResponse as RootOject;

foreach (object[] sd in jsonResponse.staticdata)
{
    foreach (object o in sd)
    {
        //Value val = v as Value;
        Value val = (Value)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(Value));
            log.Info("date: " + val.date);
            log.Info("crashCount: " + val.longValue);
   }
}
```

but in converttype from object to Value is crashing, am I missing something here.

Value is below class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Value
{
    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "longValue")]
    public long longValue{ get; set; }
}
```

modified code read Values (IgnoreDataMember Values), and then could able to read as below:  is this the right approach?

```
object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response);

RootObject jsonResponse = objResponse as RootOject;

foreach (Value in jsonResponse.Values)
{
            log.Info("date: " + val.date);
            log.Info("longValue: " + val.longValue);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034220/parse-an-array-as-a-json-string-using-datacontractjsonserializer-wp7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174549/how-to-use-datacontractjsonserializer-to-parse-a-nested-json-object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034220/parse-an-array-as-a-json-string-using-datacontractjsonserializer-wp7
and so on... 3seconds of googling

Comment: Why dont you use Json.Net? It is much more easier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parse an array as a Json string using DataContractJsonSerializer WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034220/parse-an-array-as-a-json-string-using-datacontractjsonserializer-wp7)

Comment: ok, but here  [
          "2013-06-01",
          123
        ], doesn't have any name..

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to deserialize your JSON, you can use a code-generation tool like http://json2csharp.com/ or [Paste JSON As Classes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/) and get the following data model, which works perfectly well with `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> staticdata { get; set; }
}
```

`object` works because `DataContractJsonSerializer` automatically recognizes and serializes known primitive types such as `string` and `int`.

But what you may want is to deserialize your `"staticdata"` array to a list of classes such as this:

```
public class Value
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}
```

If so, you can make use of a surrogate property in the `RootObject` type to do the conversion:

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    object[][] staticdata
    {
        get
        {
            if (Values == null)
                return null;
            return Values.Select(v => new object[] { v.Date, v.IntValue }).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            Values = value.Select(a => new Value 
                { 
                    Date = a.Length < 1 ? null : (string)Convert.ChangeType(a[0], typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    IntValue = a.Length < 2 ? 0 : (int)Convert.ChangeType(a[1], typeof(int), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
                }
                ).ToList();
        }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

In your updated question you asked, *but in converttype from object to Value is crashing, am I missing something here?*

Your problem is that you are trying to use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert an `object` to a `Value`, but this method is only for *primitive* data types that can be converted from and to strings.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> ChangeType is a general-purpose conversion method that converts the object specified by value to conversionType. The value parameter can be an object of any type, and conversionType can also be a Type object that represents any base or custom type. **For the conversion to succeed, value must implement the [`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, because the method simply wraps a call to an appropriate `IConvertible` method.**

As your `Value` type does not implement this interface, conversion fails.

Instead, you should use `Convert.ChangeType` on the individual entries in the nested arrays.  Given your `RootObject` looks like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object [][] staticdata { get; set; }
}
```

You should do:

```
using System.Linq;

DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
var jsonResponse = (RootObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response);

var query = jsonResponse.staticdata
    // For each object [] array in the outer array
    .Select(a => new Value
        {
             // Convert the inner array to a Value, using the first element for the date and the second element for the longValueand the second element for the longValue
            date = a.Length < 1 ? null : (string)Convert.ChangeType(a[0], typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            longValue = a.Length < 2 ? 0 : (long)Convert.ChangeType(a[1], typeof(long), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        });

foreach (var val in query)
{
    log.Info("date: " + val.date);
    log.Info("crashCount: " + val.longValue);
}
```